# How to ignore exact filenames in .gitignore? (without substrings)

Tags: git, gitignore

Lets say that I have a file which contains sensitive information called `secrets/passwords.txt`.
I want git to ignore this file, but upload another file named `/secrets/passwords.txt.template` which contains that key names without the passwords themselves.

How can I write a logic in `.gitignore` that ignores `secrets/passwords.txt`, but includes `secrets/passwords.txt.template`?

Comment: Just add `secrets/passwords.txt` to .gitignore? Can you show a case where this doesn't work?

Comment: My psychic powers tells me you're already tracking both files and now want to add something to .gitignore to make future commits stop caring about the passwords.txt file. I say this because just adding `secrets/passwords.txt` to your .gitignore file should not ignore the template file. If this is the case, then nothing you add in .gitignore will do what you want. You have to stop tracking the file altogether, either by committing a deletion of that file, or rewriting history so that the file is no longer tracked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add the file you want to ignore, like:

```
secrets/passwords.txt
```

Note, that in order to explicitly negate ignoring (which should not be necessary in your case), you can use `!` prefix, like:

```
!secrets/passwords.txt.template  //! will negate the instruction
```

Comment: This shouldn't be necessary. Only have to list `secrets/passwords.txt`, the template file will not be caught by this.

Comment: That's what I initially wrote, and then changed it for explicit instruction because last one got downvoted.

Comment: Then that might be because if someone asks "How can do X? I tried Y", and then if the answer is "Just do Y", then a comment is the way to go. There has to be more to the question in this case.

Comment: He, at least, didn't mention he tried. He just asked the question - *how to do X?*.

Comment: Yes, I thought it was sort of implied that he must have tried the naive solution, but you're right, I don't know if he did.